# The sequence of past actions for relative clauses - "I have put the note I found on the road" vs "I put the note I found on the road"

Tags: relative-clauses

> **I have put** the note **I found** on the road in my pocket.
>
> **I put** the note **I found** on the road in my pocket.

Is it right the first sentence is more correct because we emphasize the right sequence of the actions with Present Perfect? Can I consider the second sentence as grammatically inaccurate and if I use "I put" then I need to use "I had found" to express the right sequence of the actions?

> **I put** the note **I had found** on the road in my pocket.

Comment: Do you have a road in your pocket?

Comment: Neither sentence is any better or worse than the other as far as the choice of tense is concerned. That choice is relevant only to the context in which the person is speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @Michael Harvey has said, there is a misplaced modifier problem in your examples.  We could instead say

> I have put in my pocket the note I found on the road.

> I put in my pocket the note I found on the road.

As the context is clear, both these examples are fine.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of inserting the word **these** into your answer to make it clear that you are referring to your suggestions and not the questioner's examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually argue that in this case, though not ideal, your word choose and order is fine. Repositioning the modifier would help clarify what the sentence means, but as “put” is not usually used with “on the road,” it should be somewhat less ambiguous than other examples of misplaced modifiers.